# how do I move grub to SATA drive from USB flash? And make new GRUB boot ubuntu server from USB?

Tags: grub2

I have a weird situation at hand.

I've no ext monitor for my server.

I was loading ubuntu server from USB flash drive, till I decided to add some real HDD. After adding hdd (SATA) server doesn't boot. because new drive has no GRUB installed and since it's higher priority than usb drive, bios tries to load OS from there and fails.

Now, I see only 1 solution (except buying a new vga monitor).

Hook up HDD and USB to my laptop. Boot from live cd, install GRUB to HDD and configur it to load OS from USB flash.

Is this possible?

Please help, any tutorial will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this.

Boot from Live CD.

Mount boot drive.

Grub-install to HDD.

And it worked!